# MySQL select rows based on previous and next rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table looking like:

```
          mytable
category |      begintime
---------|----------------------
cat1     | 2016-09-25 15:00:00
cat2     | 2016-09-25 16:00:00
cat1     | 2016-09-25 17:30:00
cat3     | 2016-09-25 19:00:00
cat1     | 2016-09-25 20:00:00
  :                 :
```

Note that it doesn't have an ID-number, the `begintime` column is my primary key.

In the end, I would like to select all rows that are surrounded by a certain category, that is, to select all rows such that the category from the previous row is `@catBefore` and the category from the next row is `@catAfter`.

For example, what I would like is something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE previousRow.category = 'cat1' AND nextRow.category = 'cat1'
```

resulting in

```
    SELECT * FROM ...
category |      begintime
---------|----------------------
cat2     | 2016-09-25 16:00:00
cat3     | 2016-09-25 19:00:00
  :                 :
```

The `previousRow` and `nextRow` in this, don't seem to be definable.

**Idea**

I have tried some things, but nothing has worked out yet. One of my ideas was to first select the previous and next category as new columns, so something like:

```
SELECT mytable.*, 
       previousRow.category AS prevCat, 
       nextRow.category AS nextCat 
FROM mytable, [stuff-I-don't-know]
```

resulting in

```
     SELECT mytable.* ...
category |      begintime       | prevCat | nextCat
---------|----------------------|---------|---------
cat1     | 2016-09-25 15:00:00  | null    | cat2
cat2     | 2016-09-25 16:00:00  | cat1    | cat1
cat1     | 2016-09-25 17:30:00  | cat2    | cat3
cat3     | 2016-09-25 19:00:00  | cat1    | cat1
cat1     | 2016-09-25 20:00:00  | cat3    | ...
  :                 :
```

and then filtering using a `WHERE` clause.

Is this idea possible, or could it be done in some other way?

Comment: Do you want to query whole table for making  those prev and next category and filter then?

Comment: Lets say your first four rows are from `cat1`... If you were looking for prev and next equals `cat1`, you should return second record only or the third one should be returned as well?

Comment: @FelyppOliveira if that would be the case, then both the second and the third record are preceded and succeeded by 'cat1', hence should both be returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses correlated subqueries.  This should be okay performance-wise, if you do indeed have primary key declarations:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (select t2.category
              from mytable t2
              where t2.begintime < t.begintime
              order by begintime desc
              limit 1
             ) as prev_category,        
             (select t2.category
              from mytable t2
              where t2.begintime > t.begintime
              order by begintime asc
              limit 1
             ) as next_category
  from mytable t
 ) t
where prev_category = @cat1 and next_category = @cat2;
```

EDIT:

You can do this with variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@pn := (case when (@pcy := @pn) = NULL then -1 -- never gets here 
                           when (@pn := category) = NULL then -1 -- never gets here
                           else @pcy
                      end)
                   ) as next_category
      from (select t.*,
                   (@pc := (case when (@pcx := @pc) = NULL then -1 -- never gets here 
                                 when (@pc := category) = NULL then -1 -- never gets here
                                 else @pcx
                            end)
                   ) as prev_category
            from t cross join
                 (select @pc := '') params
            order by t.begintime
           ) t cross join
           (select @pn := '') params
      order by t.begintime desc
     ) t
where prev_category = @cat1 and next_category = @cat2;
```

Comment: Add `Limit 1` in your sub queries else this will throw error `sub query returns more than one row`

Comment: I was about to comment that too. However it doesn't perform really fast, but that could be due to the fact that my table is rather large. It has been running for minutes now without returning something. Could I easily limit this to the first 1000 or so rows to see if it indeed works?

Comment: @konewka . . . Yes, you can add a `limit` to the outer query to see how it works.  Do you indeed have an index on `begintime`?

Comment: Welcome Gordon :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I had first set it as a `PRIMARY KEY`, but have now added an `INDEX`. However, even adding a `LIMIT 10` at the end, still doesn't terminate for now. I exported a portion (1000 entries) into a seperate table and then the query yielded the right result in ~0.11s, but runtime in the original table (~16000 entries) is too high as it is still running after three minutes (which I think is weird as this should not be an exponential time grow, should it?).

Comment: @GordonLinoff, your edit doesn't give me any results, when I look at the inner query (that is, without the `SELECT t.* FROM` and `WHERE...`, the columns `prev_category` and `next_category` are always empty.

Comment: @konewka . . . Are you sure you have the `:=` and `=` set up correctly?  Can you set up a small SQL Fiddle?

Comment: @GordonLinoff sqlfiddle isn't cooperating at all, I can't seem to make it work to even input my table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is working really, really slow, but it finally executed the query, after about ten tries. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f62d5/1. Gives back no records

Answer (score 1):

I did this one... it seems to work, but it seems too slow actually... =\ I'll try to improve it. Please, check if it works for you:

```
SELECT 
  t1.category,
  t1.begintime
FROM myTable t1 -- current
INNER JOIN myTable t2 ON 1=1 -- prev
  AND t2.begintime < t1.begintime
INNER JOIN myTable t3 ON 1=1 -- next
  AND t3.begintime > t1.begintime
LEFT JOIN myTable t4 ON 1=1 -- between current and prev
  AND t4.begintime < t1.begintime
  AND t4.begintime > t2.begintime
LEFT JOIN myTable t5 ON 1=1 -- between current and next
  AND t5.begintime > t1.begintime
  AND t5.begintime < t3.begintime
WHERE 1=1
  AND t2.category = 'cat1' -- prev cat
  AND t3.category = 'cat1' -- next cat
  AND t4.begintime IS NULL -- nothing between current and prev
  AND t5.begintime IS NULL -- nothing between current and next
;
```

Comment: It doesn't give me back anything unfortunately. It executes, but no results

Comment: I tried it and against your sample data and got the expected result. What prev and next category you'd run it? If your data does not have any category between those prev and next, the expected result is an empty set... the query might be working well... I think your filter/data should not be matching anything... can you extract other sample data?

Comment: Ah yes I see, it now also works on my table, must have made a mistake copying. However, it takes about 7 seconds to evaluate the query on 1000 entry table, opposed to the ~0.11 seconds Gordon Linoff's query takes. I've also tried running it on my original ~16000 entry table, but it has been running for 5 minutes now without result, would you think the query could be improved?

Comment: I've said it was slow... I think it can be improved, but I can't do it right now... feel free to accept any other answer... I'll edit my post later if I improve the performance.